# Determining whether the evaluation mapping $p \mapsto \frac{d}{dx}\bigg|_p$ is smooth

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative, smooth-functions

For some reason, this quetion gives me a mental block: Suppose that we have the mapping $f(a, p) = a\cdot \frac{d}{dx}\bigg|_p$ for $a, p \in \mathbb{R}$, and we'd like to argue why this is a smooth mapping. Evidently the first partial derivative exists and is continuous for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$. But what about the partial derivative w.r.t. $p$? In this case, what would it even mean to take the partial derivative of the evaluation value?

Comment: So, what are domain and codomain of $f$? What I mean is: on what kind of function is $f(a, p)$ supposed to act? Smooth? $C^1$?

Comment: @JoMo The domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}\times [0, 2\pi)$ and the codomain is the tangent bundle $TS^1$ of the unit circle. That is, $f$ maps to the vector field elements of $TS^1$.